# team working on google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I use google map api v2 on my android application. I worked on it in my pc now I wanna work with team. So I just moved the project to another pc and ran the application. Then on new pc, I got blank map on my map page.

How can I fix this? I think it might belong to hash key of google map api!

Comment: did you check error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a debug key in your console for each computer since each debug key is different